# References in Workspace are collapsed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

When I use ctrl+shift+G to find references for an object in eclipse, I will get a list of those, but they are collapsed like this:

[image: references]

Why being collapsed?

Those four occurences are method calls on the object. I expect to be able to see which method calls that are called on the object by looking in this list. Can that be made?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the highlighted line. Does it not expand when you double-click on it? If not, Eclipse is misbehaving. Happens all the time. Exit, maybe close some other applications to free up memory, then reopen Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Matches within a single method in a class are always just shown as 'n matches'. There is no way to expand this in the search results view (see [Eclipse bug 46051](http://eclip.se/46051)).